# Persistent search result tabs in Thunderbird?

Tags: thunderbird, search, tabs, persistent

How can I make search result tabs in Thunderbird persistent between sessions?

For example: I make a search in Thunderbird and get the search results in a new tab. However, after a restart of Thunderbird, the tab is no more there.

So how can I make this search results tab persistent?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot make the search results persistent.

The work around is to create **Filter Rules**(Select the email account > Manage message filters > New > Enter filter name > Select rule parameters) in each of your saved email accounts to match your search string and apply an **Action** (like tagging or moving messages to a custom folder of your choice)

I think the combination of message filter with tagging will do the trick of 'saving the search'.